# Plotly python: Multiple item selection interactive plot

Tags: python, plot, plotly, interactive

I want to be able to select multiple items instead of only one or all. So far I am only able to select one item and display its graph, or select 'all'
and display all the graphs.

I want to be able to select 2 or more items and have their plot be displayed in a single graph shown below.

I am new to plotly so any help is very much appreciated. Thank you so much :)

[image]

My code:

```
def interactive_multi_plot(actual, forecast_1, forecast_2, title, addAll = True):
fig = go.Figure()
    

for column in forecast_1.columns.to_list():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = forecast_1.index,
            y = forecast_1[column],
            name = "Forecast_SI"
        )

    )

    
    button_all = dict(label = 'All',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': forecast_1.columns.isin(forecast_1.columns),
                           'title': 'All',
                           'showlegend':True}])
    
for column in forecast_2.columns.to_list():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = forecast_2.index,
            y = forecast_2[column],
            name = "Forecast_LSTM" 
        )

    )

    
    button_all = dict(label = 'All',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': forecast_2.columns.isin(forecast_2.columns),
                           'title': 'All',
                           'showlegend':True}])
for column in actual.columns.to_list():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = actual.index,
            y = actual[column],
            name = "True values" 
        )

    )

    
    button_all = dict(label = 'All',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': actual.columns.isin(actual.columns),
                           'title': 'All',
                           'showlegend':True}])
    
fig.layout.plot_bgcolor = '#010028'
fig.layout.paper_bgcolor = '#010028'
def create_layout_button(column):
    return dict(label = column,
                method = 'update',
                args = [{'visible': actual.columns.isin([column]),
                         'title': column,
                         'showlegend': True}])
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        active = 0,
        buttons = ([button_all] * addAll) +  list(actual.columns.map(lambda column: create_layout_button(column)))
        )
    ]     
)
# Update remaining layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    title_text=title,
    height=800,
    font = dict(color='#fff', size=12)
)


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight forward in **dash** as https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown supports
multi-select and search

- setup

  1. minor changes to your function. define **meta** attribute of traces for later use in dash callback
  2. simulate some data as it's not provided in question.  Three data frames (actuals, forecast 1 & forecast 2)
  3. creation of figure using modified version of your code
- integrate into **dash** app

#### setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def interactive_multi_plot(actual, forecast_1, forecast_2, title, addAll = True):
    fig = go.Figure()
    for column in forecast_1.columns.to_list():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x = forecast_1.index,y = forecast_1[column],name = "Forecast_SI",meta = column))

    for column in forecast_2.columns.to_list():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x = forecast_2.index,y = forecast_2[column],name = "Forecast_LSTM" ,meta = column))
    for column in actual.columns.to_list():
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x = actual.index,y = actual[column],name = "True values" ,meta = column))

    fig.layout.plot_bgcolor = '#010028'
    fig.layout.paper_bgcolor = '#010028'

    #  Update remaining layout properties
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text=title,
        height=800,
        font = dict(color='#fff', size=12)
    )

    return fig

S = 100
C = 10

actual = pd.DataFrame({
        c: np.sort(np.random.uniform(0, 600, S))
        for c in [f"{a}{b}-{c}" for a, b, c in zip(np.random.randint(100, 200, C),
                                                   np.random.choice(list("ABCDEF"), C),
                                                   np.random.randint(300, 400, C),)]
})

f1 = actual.assign(**{c:actual[c]*1.1 for c in actual.columns})
f2 = actual.assign(**{c:actual[c]*1.2 for c in actual.columns})

fig = interactive_multi_plot(actual, f1, f2, "Orders")
```

#### dash app

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="lines",
            options=[{"label": c, "value": c} for c in actual.columns.tolist()],
            value=None,
            multi=True
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="interactive-multiplot", figure=fig),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("interactive-multiplot", "figure"),
    Input("lines", "value"),
    State("interactive-multiplot", "figure"),
)
def updateGraphCB(lines, fig):
    # filter traces...
    fig = go.Figure(fig).update_traces(visible=False)
    for line in [] if not lines else lines:
        fig.update_traces(visible=True, selector={"meta":line})
    return fig

app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Rob! Could you please explain what are you doing in the set up part of the code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help! I do not understand why now the lines are linear, and the graph looks completely different from the original graph. Also, why the item names is different and why are you randomly selecting? Thank you!

Comment: the only use of random is generation of data frames, nothing to do with plotting.  You did not provide sample data,  so I simulated it so I could make this call `fig = interactive_multi_plot(actual, f1, f2, "Orders")` simplest way if you want me to investigate is provide sample data for all three data frames so I'm not having to assume how it may or may not be structured